# How do we iterate and access associative away team's score in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop, associative-array

How do we access the away team's score from this associative array?  Below is the output of the associative array when doing a print_r in PHP using the accessor $preGamesSorted[$e][away][score] but nothing shows.

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [state] => final
        [startTimeDisplay] => 12:00 PM ET
        [startTimeEpoch] => 1426262400
        [home] => Array
            (
                [rank] => 24
                [name] => Davidson
                [winner] => true
                [record] => 24-6
                [score] => 67
            )

        [away] => Array
            (
                [rank] => 0
                [name] => La Salle
                [winner] => false
                [record] => 17-16
                [score] => 66
            )

    )
```

Here is the php code:

```
    <?php
 $url = file_get_contents("http://i.turner.ncaa.com/sites/default/files/external/test/scoreboard.json");
 $turnerNCAAJsonObject = json_decode($url,true);

 $liveGames = array();
 $finalGames = array();
 $preGames = array();

for ($n = 0; $n <= count($turnerNCAAJsonObject); $n++) {
    if(isset($turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state]) && $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state] == 'final') {
        array_push($finalGames, $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n]);
    }elseif (isset($turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state]) && $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state] == 'pre') {
        array_push($preGames, $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n]);
    }elseif ($turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n][state] == 'live') {
        array_push($liveGames, $turnerNCAAJsonObject[$n]);
    }
}
print_r($liveGames);

$finalGamesSorted = value_sort($finalGames, 'startTimeEpoch');
echo "<font color=\"red\"><h3>Sorted Final Games</h3></font>";
//start of display for sorted final games
for ($e = 0; $e <= count($finalGamesSorted); $e++) {
    echo "<font color=\"red\">";
    echo "Game Status: " . strtoupper($finalGamesSorted[$e][state]);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $preGamesSorted[$e][home][name] . " (" . $preGamesSorted[$e][home][rank] . ")" . " -VERSUS- " . $preGamesSorted[$e][away][name] . " (" . $preGamesSorted[$e][away][rank] . ")";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Home Team's Record: " . $preGamesSorted[$e][home][record] . " -VERSUS- Away Team's Record: " . $preGamesSorted[$e][away][record];
    echo "<br>";
    //print_r($preGamesSorted[$e][startTimeEpoch]);
    echo "</font>";
    echo "<h3>" . $preGamesSorted[$e][home][score] . "-" . $preGamesSorted[$e][away][score] . "</h3>";
    //echo $preGamesSorted[$e][home][score];
    foreach ($finalGamesSorted[$e] as $title => $gameSpecifics) {
            foreach ($gameSpecifics as $stateKey => $stateValue){
                echo "<b><u>";
                print "$stateKey : $stateValue<br />";
                echo "</b></u>";
            }
                echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

The array output is what shows when doing a print_r on the variable $finalGamesSorted.  Also the function value_sort, sorts the array by one of its numerical keys.

Comment: remove `[$e]` from the accessor and add `[0]`, also add your php code in post

Comment: And also put quotes around the literal key strings: `$preGamesSorted[0]['away']['score']` ...

Comment: check once what @ChetanAmeta says, and tell what happen?

Comment: After trying both removing the [$e] and putting quotes around the literal key strings, it still doesn't show the score.

Comment: what does `value_sort` function do and what is the value of `$finalGamesSorted` variable

Answer (score 0):

You forgot '' in your array key access. In should be

```
$preGamesSorted[$e]['home']['name'] // Home
$preGamesSorted[$e]['away']['name'] // Away
```

Comment: The home and away names are showing up however we can't get the scores to show for some strange reason.